# Trying to do a For If and Loop in email outlook subject title

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've been trawling around the forums and have pieced together a mix of codes. The idea of this code is to create an email based on a fixed criteria. Multiple unique identifiers of this fixed criteria will be listed in the email (either in the body/subject title) and a word document will be attached to the email.

I'm having issues having the unique identifiers listed and having their word documents attached. Here is the code i've pieced together so far.

```
Sub Email_Outlook()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim MailDoc As Outlook.MailItem
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailDoc = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim Mail_worksheet As Worksheet
Dim Mail_worksheet1 As Worksheet
Set Mail_worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Set Mail_worksheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send")

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As String

Dim c As Integer
Dim d As String

b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4)
d = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4)

For a = 0 To b - 1

    'Check Production Selection
    If Mail_worksheet.Cells(17, 2 + a) = "ProductA" And Mail_worksheet.Cells(15, 2 + a) = Mail_worksheet1.Cells(7, 6) Then
        MailDoc.Subject = "Word document for ProductA - " & Format(Date, "DD MMM YYYY")

        For c = 0 To d - 1
        If Mail_worksheet.Cells(17, 2 + a) = "ProductA" And Mail_worksheet.Cells(15, 2 + a) = Mail_worksheet1.Cells(7, 6) Then
        MailDoc.Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Word documents attached for:" & vbCrLf & _
                Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + c)

        End If

        Next c

    End If

Next a

MailDoc.Attachments.Add ("file:///c:\users\word doc\") & Mail_worksheet.Cells(4, 2 + c) & Like "*.docx"
MailDoc.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need something like this

i could not figure out why you had two loops and two `If` statements, so i took them out

also, it is a bad idea to use variable names that look like system objects eg. `email_Worksheet` looks like `Worksheet` at first glance

```
Sub Email_Outlook()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim mailDoc As Outlook.MailItem
    Set mailDoc = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim emailWs As Worksheet
    Set emailWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")

    Dim sendWs As Worksheet
    Set sendWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send")

    Dim b As Integer
    b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")    '  Cells(1, 4)

    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 0 To b - 1

        'Check Production Selection
        If emailWs.Cells(17, 2 + a) = "ProductA" And emailWs.Cells(15, 2 + a) = sendWs.Cells(7, 6) Then
            mailDoc.Subject = "Word document for ProductA - " & Format(Date, "DD MMM YYYY")
            mailDoc.Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    "Word documents attached for:" & vbCrLf & _
                    emailWs.Cells(4, 2 + a)
        End If

    Next a

    mailDoc.Attachments.Add "c:\users\word doc\" & emailWs.Cells(4, 2 + c) & ".docx"
    mailDoc.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey jsotola, thanks for your help! this worked but it seemed to only display the last unique identifier in the list (a vast improvement to what i could do). Reason why I had the double loop was cause i was trying to have the code display more unique identifiers if there are.

Also, for the attachment, i have to use the * wild card as the file name after the unique identifier varies. Do you know how this works? I haven't seen this around before.